# declaring a BoxLayout the same way of the other component

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

hello i am trying to declare a BoxLayout the same way of declaring the BorderLayout

the way of declaring the borderlayout

```
JPanel textFiled = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    textFiled.add(enterText,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

but it is not working with BoxLayout because it is for one Component and width and i watched some tutorial some are declaring a a method but i don't wanna to do that so i tried to put it in other JPanel and nothing happens

```
JPanel t = new JPanel();
        t.add(startTime);
        t.add(endTime);

        JPanel timing = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(t, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

and what will happen if i set the width as 50 for example and what are my chooses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create the panel and set the BoxLayout in one statement (like you do for the BorderLayout). You need to use two statements since the BoxLayout needs a reference to the panel that you want to use as a BoxLayout.

1)  Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html). It will show you how to create a panel using a BoxLayout and how to add components to the panel.

2) Or, you can check out the `Box` class. It is a convenience class that will allow you to create a container using a BoxLayout in a single statement.

```
Box timing = new Box(...);
timing.add( t );
```

Take a look at the table of contents for the tutorial as it contains many tutorial on basic Swing functionality.